# how to access html name in modelforms instead of model name in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

How to assign custom name to modelform in django like..

```
 <input name="product_stock" class="form-control" type="text" id="productStock" placeholder="">
```

instead of `name='product_stock'`
access tag with `ProductStock` in model form and how to assign in view.py

forms.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = [
            'product_name', 'product_image', 'product_stock', 'product_status', 
            'product_added_use', 'product_deleted_user'
        ]
```

page.html

```
<form class="pl-3 pr-3" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group"> 
       <label for="productName">Product Name</label>
       <input name='product_name' class="form-control" type="text" id="productName" required="" placeholder="Michael Zenaty">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="productimage">Product Image</label>
        <input name="product_image" class="form-control" type="file" id="productimage"  placeholder="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="productStock">Product Stock</label>
        <input name="product_stock" class="form-control" type="text" id="productStock" placeholder="">
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm following what you're asking for correctly but you can use template filters to access anything you've set as `context` in your `views.py`

def view(request):

```
context = {
    'someNameHere': some.object.here
}

return render(request, 'main/view.html', context)
```

then in your templates you can use `{{ someNameHere }}` to access it.